# How to get complete path in grails controller

Tags: grails-2.0

I want to use something similar to HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo(); which returns the entire path of request. This is used in java, I am trying to find something similar in Grails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `request` object is an instance of the Servlet API's HttpServletRequest interface.

You should try that in your controller : (in order to show the entire path of the request in the webpage)

```
def index = { render request.forwardURI }
```